# Can someone please explain how the syndrome bit still ends up being 0 in this quantum error correction circuit using repetition code?

Tags: qiskit, measurement, error-correction

[image]

I'm not too great at dealing with superpositions and applying the CNOT gate when superpositions are involved. Can you go through it in detail each gate using math/matrices etc. It's based on the quantum error correction (using repetition codes) part of the Qiskit textbook.

Link to the specific page in the textbook: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/error-correction-repetition-code.html

Comment: If you are talking about the 0 to the right of the downwards error of the measurement operator, that’s the index of the classical bit in which the measurement is stored, not the measurement result

Comment: @epelaaez, you are correct about that. However, it is also true that the measurement result for this circuit will indeed always be 0.

Comment: Yes, it will be 0, can you explain how though using each gate step by step?

Answer (score 1):

You have the initial state $|000\rangle$. The first Hadamard gate on qubit zero sends the register to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|000\rangle + |100\rangle\right)$. Then, the $\text{CX}$ controlled on qubit zero and target on qubit one takes the state to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|000\rangle + |110\rangle\right)$. And the next $\text{CX}$ between qubit zero and qubit two takes it to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|000\rangle + |111\rangle\right)$. At this point we have a maximally entangled $\text{GHZ}$ state, but we are still missing a final $\text{CX}$ gate. This is between qubit one and two, with qubit one being the control. Thus, the final state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|000\rangle + |110\rangle\right)$. Therefore, as you can see, qubit three will always be projected into $|0\rangle$ when measured in the $Z$ basis.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!